# What does "E" stand for in a polar curve?

Tags: aircraft-performance, polar-curve

In the following polar curve, there is a symbol "E" with the number 33.5 next to it. What does this mean?

[image: Polar Curve ASK-21]

Answer (score 2):

E is used as the symbol for L/D in German. Normally, a symbol description will call it "Gleitzahl" (glide ratio).